# How to hide a column in google visualization table?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-visualization

I am new to google api and i had doubts in google visualization table.

My question is there any possible way to hide a particular column in visualization datatable.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cssClass = {rowNumberCell: 'rowNumberCellClass'};

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Place');
  data.addRows(4);
  data.setCell(0, 0, 'John');
  data.setCell(1, 0, 'Sam');
  data.setCell(2, 0, 'Andreson');
  data.setCell(3, 0, 'Cody');

  data.setCell(0, 1, 'Stockholm');
  data.setCell(1, 1, 'Dubai');   
  data.setCell(2, 1, 'India');
  data.setCell(3, 1, 'Australia');

  visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tableContainer'));

  visualization.draw(data, {
      allowHtml: true, 
      showRowNumber: true, 
      cssClassNames: cssClass  
  }

  );

  }  
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="tableContainer"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

In the above code , I used 'view' option as follows :

```
visualization.draw(data, {
      allowHtml: true, 
      showRowNumber: true, 
      cssClassNames: cssClass,
      view: {columns: [0]}
  });
```

It is not working.

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class)-instance as data and set the columns  via `setColumns`:

```js
var cssClass = {rowNumberCell: 'rowNumberCellClass'};

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Place');
  data.addRows(4);
  data.setCell(0, 0, 'John');
  data.setCell(1, 0, 'Sam');
  data.setCell(2, 0, 'Andreson');
  data.setCell(3, 0, 'Cody');

  data.setCell(0, 1, 'Stockholm');
  data.setCell(1, 1, 'Dubai');   
  data.setCell(2, 1, 'India');
  data.setCell(3, 1, 'Australia');

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  
  view.setColumns([0]);//only use the first column 
  
  var visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tableContainer'));

  visualization.draw(view, {
      allowHtml: true, 
      showRowNumber: true, 
      cssClassNames: cssClass
  }

  );

  }  
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

```html
<div id="tableContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
</script>
```

Comment: I have a table with 10K rows and 9 columns, I want to show/hide columns on checkbox selections, I know I can redraw the view on click event in javascript depending on the checkbox selection but this takes some time to redraw everytime, is it possible to show/hide only one column dynamically just like highcharts provide this feature?